# hg status with multiple remotes

Tags: version-control, mercurial, hg

I am trying to use mercurial and work with multiple pull repos and a single push repo.

I have tried changing the .hg/hgrc and is as given below:

```
[paths]
default = remoteA
mine = remoteB
default-push = remoteB
```

How do I check for changes in my working directory when compared to the remoteB repo? I tried using hg status but this checks for diffs between the default repo and working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for `hg outgoing`.

You use `hg status` to see lists of changed files. You can compare either two commits against each other — this shows you what files changed from revision 10 to 20:

```
$ hg status --rev 10:20
```

or your can compare the working copy against a revision — this shows you changes made compared with the working copy parent revision:

```
$ hg status
```

and this shows you changes since revision 10:

```
$ hg status --rev 10
```

When you work with multiple repositories, then you can `hg pull` the changes from another repository into your local repository. You can then use `hg status` like above to compare revisions. You can also use `hg log` to see what has changed.

Using `hg incoming` is just like first using `hg pull` and then using `hg log` to list the new commits. That is normally the command used to see what is new in a remote repository. You can then later decide to actually pull the commits into your repository.

Comment: I tried using `hg outgoing` but I guess it does not seem to recognize any new unversioned files. Is this true or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Notice the big difference between comparing **files** and looking at **changesets**. The `hg outgoing` command is showing you changesets, and will thus by definition only care about committed files.

Comment: aah, right. The `hg outgoing` does work in showing a changeset status. If I were understanding this right if my default remote is atleast a changeset in the future, thats when a `hg incoming` be useful.

Comment: Yes, exactly, `hg incoming` shows what the next `hg pull` would bring down (and `hg outgoing` shows what `hg push` would send).